# mysql and php with restler for webservice

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, rest

Does anyone know how to code restler to work with php and mysql to produce something like the following:

I want to create a XML API Web Service and not sure where to start.

I want people to be able to query the database for information such as the following using a http request.

Example of Data

BrandName

Price

ShortDescription

SKU

Example Query

http://website.com/productxml?dep=1&Count=3&BrandName=Y&Price=Y

How would I go about writing such a script as I have searched the internet and cant find any examples and was wondering if you can help.

Thanks in advance

Roy

Answer (score 0):

You could use Restler (http://luracast.com/products/restler/) and build a method

```
class YourClass {
    public function productxml($dep, $Count, $BrandName, $Price) {
        // your MySQL stuff
    }
}
```

which handles your request.

See the examples (http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/) how this can be done.

Hope this helps.
Greets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Restler @[Restler Luracast](http://luracast.com/products/restler/).
The development has increased alot and its stable.

The fun part about this framework is that it supports multiple formats. All these formats can be added by just inserting a single line of code:

```
require_once '../../../vendor/restler.php'; 
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
$r = new Restler();
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat'); <---- Add format here
$r->addAPIClass('BMI');
$r->handle();
```

Also I would like to refer to my Luracast Restler template on bitbucket its public and its there for everybody to see.

I combined Restler with Doctrine so catching data from databases has never been easier. Its a raw version for now but I'll update it soon.

My version uses vagrant. Its a extension to virtualisation technology that makes development setup easy and fast. Once your application is ready you can deploy it to your server.

Link:[Restler+Doctrine](https://Ne0h@bitbucket.org/Ne0h/restler-doctrine.git)

1) Install virtualbox + vagrant

2) Clone my repository

3) Move to the cloned directory.

4) vagrant up

5) Enjoy and start programming your REST API in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Repository has been made private. Can you update the link please?